# Connect from windows to distant FTP server through the sharing connection

Tags: bluetooth, windows, xiaomi, ftp

I have a Mi mix 2s phone (good phone) but I have an issue with it.
I'm a webdevelopper and I'm sharing my 4G connection to my computer (Windows 10) but I can not use FTP (to connect to a distant server) on my computer. It's not connecting. I tried it by creating a wifi network and also by sharing my connection through USB and none are working. I never had an issue before with my previous phone, this is the first time it's not working. I think I just have something to activate but I'm not able to find what.
Does anybody had this issue?

Thx,

Comment: Is your phone rooted? Are you using some firewall app on phone?

Comment: Not rooted and no firewall (And I should not need to)
The phone is straight from the box, I only activated the developper mode.
I had 10 different android phones and it's the first time it's happening...

Comment: Anybody? 
I'm a bit stuck, I will have to change the phone...

Comment: You will have to troubleshoot the issue yourself. Use network tools `ping`, `nmap` etc. to find out where the packets get dropped. Are you able to connect to FTP server from phone?